# How Can I create word in contenteditable div, which can not remove (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, terminal, textarea, contenteditable, caret

I try do something like terminal in JS, and I need create word 'current source, current location' (for example:admin@ubuntuTLS~$: ~/Desktop) at the beggining, that can not remove and, so that caret cannot be moved back on front of it. I was trying something do with window.range() on 'input' event ( for not move caret to back it):

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-cursor-position-in-content-editable-element-using-javascript/amp/

But it doesn't work. I don't know What Can I do.

[this is that 'word (location) '](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utcxh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, this defaults to the user name of the computer. Open console in chrome and test javascript there. [Here is simply tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open)

Comment: I thought about something other, but it's no matter, because I done it, but thanks for answear!